# Is there a way i can get a sharedpreference name?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Let's say i created a shared preference.

sp = this.getSharedPreferences("name",MODE_PRIVATE);

If i'm in another activity, is there a way i can find the name of sp and set it to a string?

Answer (score 0):

you can access the sharedpreferences with the same method you have used. use a public static varibale to hold the name in a class.

Answer (score 0):

Use a constant. a `public final static String NAME = "the_name";`. Then you can alway reference it as `NameOfTheClassWhereYouPutIt.NAME`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to refer to a given shared preference in another activity, you can pass that String key of that preference to the new Activity via its Intent when creating it.

If you simply need to find a certain preference in any activity, you can iterate over all of the preferences, and get access to all the keys (and values) that way.

Assuming your shared preferences is in the variable **mySharedPreferences**, an example of getting all of the keys and vales would be:

```
Map<String,?> preferenceMap = mySharedPreferences.getAll();
for ( Map.Entry<String, ?> keyValPair : preferenceMap.entrySet() )
{
   String key = keyValPair.getKey(); // this is your preference name
   String val = keyValPair.getValue(); // this is your preference value
}
```